# Deactivate Wizard popping up on first login

Tags: .desktop

After a fresh installation of Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop, when the user logs on the first time there is this "Run on first launch" wizard asking about Livepatch, Improve Ubuntu, Privacy and Software installation.

How can I prevent this from showing up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just happened to search on and eventually finding the right keywords. The solution can be seen on https://www.putorius.net/disable-gnome-initial-setup.html

In a nutshell simply create the correct marker file like

```
mkdir ~/.config
echo "yes" >> ~/.config/gnome-initial-setup-done
```

The other page also mentions how to deactivate the wizard for all users (current or future).

Comment: Seems to be correct because of https://codesearch.debian.net/search?q=gnome-initial-setup-done+package%3A%5CQgnome-initial-setup%5CE&literal=1 .